# Checkbox in Sheets as Enter button to Copy Data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out an onEdit function for my Google Sheet where, when a checkbox in J16 of the DATA PULL sheet is checked, it will copy the values of the cells in columns F15 to F20 and I17 to E20, then paste them into a new row on the REPORTS sheets on the respective columns and once unchecked it will move to another row, and when checked it will copy the new data.

Really need some help.

Here is the file (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19vw1mrwKcvUy66sxXV1r1e2eSlX-O862Ud-Fdi2iEQ8/edit?usp=sharing)

Sorry about that, I had to edit some confidential data and re-organize the design for easier on our end.

Comment: Please share a sample/copy of your spreadsheet.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. While a links to external resources might be helpful, questions on this site should be self-contained. Considering this, please show what you have tried directly in the question body and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Sorry missed noting on my first comment to remove sensitive data. You can replace the names with dummies such as Name1, Name2, Name3, since those details are not really required to replicate your issue. Also as Ruben stated, also share the existing script in your post if it already has even if it is in the sheets script itself. You are more likely to get help from the community if it shows you've shown some effort and not just asking to do work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: OH. I'm sorry about that. I'm really new and don't know anything about everything in appscript and sheets yet but after listening to many videos and searching on the web. I found a onEdit function that somewhat is close to what I'm looking for but uhm that's the thing, still trying to learn. I'm actually a Guidance Associate by profession and I'm trying to find ways to make our work easier. hehe

Comment: so this is what I found and I only understand a little of it and it's at the src.getRange that got me confused :
function onEdit(e) {
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;
  if (src.getName() != "Data Pull" || r.columnStart != 24 || r.rowStart <= 2 || !r.isChecked()) return;
  const dest = e.source.getSheetByName("Reports");
  src.getRange(r.rowStart, 25, 1, 2).copyTo((dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 2)), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}

Answer (score 0):

#### Creating function execution table

gs:

```
function onMyEdit(e) {//use installable so that you can perform actions requiring permissions
  //e.source.toast('Entry')
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Functions" && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.value == "TRUE" && e.range.offset(0,-1).getValue() != null) {
    //e.source.toast('working')
    let n = e.range.offset(0, -1).getDisplayValue();
    executeFunctionByName(n);
    //Logger.log(n)
    e.range.setValue("FAlSE"); //Reset checkbox
  }
}

function func1() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("func1")
}

function func2() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("func2")
}

function executeFunctionByName(func) {
  this[func]();
}
```

Functions Sheet:

[image]

Demo:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

Your data set is rather complex so I didn't produce a data set to test this but I'm pretty sure it will work for you.

1st.  Test that we are on the checkbox in J16 and that the checkbox is true.

2nd.  Get the values from I17:I20 a 2D array in the form `[[1],[2],[3]...]`

3rd.  Get the value from E15:E20 a 2D array in the form `[[4],[5],[6]...]`

4th.  Concatinate the 2 arrays `[[1],[2],[3]...[4],[5],[6]...]`

This would produce a column on a spreadsheet.  However we can use the Array.flat() to make it a row `[1,2,3...4,5,6...]`.

Lastly we simply copy the row to the other sheet but we need to convert to a 2D array to use setValues() by enclosing in array brackets [values].

**Code.gs**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  let src = e.range.getSheet();
  let dest = e.source.getSheetByName("Reports"); 
  if( src.getName() === "Data Pull" ) {
    if( ( e.range.getA1Notation() === "J16" ) {
      if( e.value ) {
        let values = src.getRange(17,9,4,1).getValues();  // I17:I20
        values = values.concat(src.getRange(15,6,6,1).getValues());  // add E15:E20
        dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,5,1,values.length).setValues([values.flat()]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Sheet.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))
- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [Range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Array.concat()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp)
- [Array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)